# Error compiling imapfilter 2.4.1 in CentOS 5.6

Tags: gcc, compilation, lua, centos, imap

I am trying to compile imapfilter 2.4.1 ( https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter ) in CentOS 5.6. I believe I've got all the dependencies sorted but when I run make I get:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/src/imapfilter-2.4.1/src'
cc -Wall -O -DMAKEFILE_SHAREDIR='"/usr/local/share/imapfilter"' -c -o core.o core.c
core.c:41: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ifcorelib’
core.c: In function ‘ifcore_append’:
core.c:947: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘lua_strlen’
core.c: In function ‘luaopen_ifcore’:
core.c:1162: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘luaL_register’
core.c:1162: error: ‘ifcorelib’ undeclared (first use in this function)
core.c:1162: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
core.c:1162: error: for each function it appears in.)
make[1]: *** [core.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/src/imapfilter-2.4.1/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Based on other user comments and file revision dates I am sure this should compile. I am guessing I'm missing a library somewhere. I'll appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from first error message:

```
core.c:41: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘ifcorelib’
```

Line 41 of core.c is:

```
static const luaL_reg ifcorelib[] = {
```

Cryptic message from gcc means that it knows nothing about what is the `luaL_reg` and it thinks that it is variable name. Then it goes into panic when reads *second* variable name in the same definition/declaration. `luaL_reg` should be something like struct.

So, it seems that your problems are located in LUA development headers. May be you have too old or even to modern Lua package.

The imapfilter's github's readme says:

> Compile time requirements are Lua (version 5.1)

Are you sure that your lua is 5.1 and the lua-devel (or any other package with lua headers) is 5.1 too?

Comment: You confirmed my suspicions about GCC not knowing what luaL_reg was. The issue may have been my use of an incorrect version of LUA. I feel pretty strongly that my issue was an incorrect version, and so I will mark this as the accepted answer. Unfortunately I've had to put this project on hold for the time being, and won’t be able to verify it until I have some more free time.